# Handling data variables in php mailer and including php file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a code like the below. I'm not able to pass the variables to the php file and send a mail.

In other words, I need to send some variable to php file, then include the php file in my body content and send it as a mail.

How to resolve it. The problem I'm getting is - The php variables defined in sample.php is not displaying in my body content.

## index.php

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
function get_include_contents($filename, $variablesToMakeLocal) {
extract($variablesToMakeLocal);
if (is_file($filename)) {
ob_start();
include $filename;
return ob_get_clean();
}
return false;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("from@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("addaddress@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test Subject";
$variable['one'] = 'my variable one';
$variable['two'] = 'my variable two';
$mail->IsHTML(true);   
$mail->Subject = "You have an event today";
$mail->Body = get_include_contents('sample.php', $variable); 
$mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

## sample.php

```
<table width='600px' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeee'><img src='logo.png' /></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#ffffff'  bordercolor='#eeeeee'>
<div style='border:1px solid #eeeeee;font-family:Segoe UI,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;padding:20px 10px;'>
<p>Variable one is <?php echo $variable['one']; ?>.</p>
<p>Variable two is <?php echo $variable['two']; ?>.</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code in `sample.php` from

```
<p>Variable one is <?php echo $variable['one']; ?>.</p>
<p>Variable two is <?php echo $variable['two']; ?>.</p>
```

into

```
<p>Variable one is <?php echo $one; ?>.</p>
<p>Variable two is <?php echo $two; ?>.</p>
```

because you used `extract` function

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in the comments, but an alternative way to tackle this is to change the code to:

```
$mail->Body = include('sample.php');
```

And in sample.php instead of echoing everything, return it. So you can either place ob_start() at the top, then ob_get_clean at the bottom of sample.php , or you can store the html in a multi-line string.

```
<?php
return <<<EOT
<table width='600px' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeee'><img src='logo.png' /></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#ffffff'  bordercolor='#eeeeee'>
<div style='border:1px solid #eeeeee;font-family:Segoe UI,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;padding:20px 10px;'>
<p>Variable one is $variable[one].</p>
<p>Variable two is $variable[two].</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
EOT
?>
```

Comment: this is not working. could you please explain this. curious to know this code too !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use **extract()** the keys of the array will be the variable names. So, in your example the variables you'll have to use in your template are **$one** and **$two**

Check the manual for more info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php